# No Route Matches Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I generated a scaffold for Studio. Now am linking from Products view

```
<%= button_to 'Customize', new_studio_path %>
```

resources :studios is placed in routes.rb

I am still getting `No route matches [POST] "/studios/new"`

If someone could help me figure this out I would appreciate it tons.

Here is a gists of the files I am working with for this. https://gist.github.com/JRizzle88/7861628

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button's default HTTP method is POST, what you need is method GET, so you need to specify this explicitly:

```
<%= button_to 'Customize', new_studio_path, method: :get %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Ninja below was 4 seconds faster

Comment: @jrizzle88 are you sure? I think I was. :)

Comment: Well, it's not the race, but I've lost. :)

Comment: @BroiSatse of course it isn't. :) Anyway, it's quite cool that we gave two almost identical answers almost simultaneously. :)

Comment: That was the creepy part when i refreshed! Are you two twins!?

Comment: No, and we live above 1,000 kilometers from each other. :P

Comment: Ok, well here we go, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457757/couldnt-find-studio-without-an-id  1  2  3  go!

Answer (score 2):

Button is sending a POST request, where your server expects a GET request for given url. You need to specify method on a button:

```
<%= button_to 'Customize', new_studio_path, method: :get %>
```

Comment: Awesome!, now I get Couldn't find Studio without an ID on my studios_controller.rb     def set_studio

      @studio = Studio.find(params[:id])

    end

Comment: @jrizzle88 it seems you don't pass your ID param. Anyway, it's the material to another question.

Answer (score 1):

The rails convention would be to use `link_to` which will send a GET request:

```
<%= link_to 'Customize', new_studio_path %>
```

Comment: This is the right answer IMO. `link_to` is for GET requests and `button_to` is for POST requests. Use CSS to style your link to look like a button if you want.