# Couldn't find Studio without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Everything seems to be in the right place but apparently not. Here is a gists with the error information in the gists description.

https://gist.github.com/JRizzle88/7862465

EDIT:

Here is what the trace begins with:

```
Started GET "/studios/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-08 13:52:41 -0600
Processing by StudiosController#new as HTML
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Studio without an ID:
....
....
```

Comment: What path you try to get to?

Comment: Your routes.rb, which probably is relevant, is also missing in gist.

Comment: new_studio_path , defined in the button that I have in products index

Comment: using resources :studios

Comment: it's on the gists now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your before_filter in your StudiosController to

```
before_action :set_studio, except: [:index, :new, :create]
```

Change your show action to

```
def show
end
```

Change your new action to

```
def new
  @studio = Studio.new
end
```

Comment: i just put @studio = Studio.new in my def index for products_controller and same error

Comment: My bad - you do not need @studio at all. Just use `new_studio_path`.

Comment: i changed new_studio_path(@studio) to just new_studio_path and still the same :(

Comment: Were does the error occur? Please update your question with a full stacktrace.

Comment: It occurs when that button is pressed within the products index

Comment: Thanks! finally got it sorted out with the help of you all, all answers were relevant to my knowledge, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There is

```
before_action :set_studio
```

in your StudiosController. `params[:id]` seems to be `nil` here and it can't find Studio with `nil` id. You should probably add `only` or `except` parameter to your before actions.

Another strange thing is

```
@studio = Studio.new(params[:id])
```

in StudiosController#new. It should be just

```
@studio = Studio.new
```

isn't it?

Comment: I added , only: [:new] to my before_action and removed (params[:id]) and still the same error, I had the (params[:id]) there just trying different things but came to a dead end on things to try which why I am here lol

Comment: No, you should replace before action by
`before_action :set_studio, except: [:index, :new, :create]`
or
`before_action :set_studio, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

Comment: @janfoeh's updated answer contains these fixes, check it out.